# Querying a timestamp by date with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize

I want to find some entries in my DB through the `createdAt` column,  but just using the date. I am using postgres and the `createdAt` is a `timestamptz`. Here is an example of what an entry in it looks like: `2019-02-27 20:17:07.05+00`

This is what the setting of my query looks like:

```
const dateString = momentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
query.createdAt = { $iLike: `%${dateString}` }
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I am getting the following error:

> retry-as-promised:error SequelizeDatabaseError: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone ~~* unknown

Is the issue perhaps because I am using a string? What is the right way to query by date?

Comment: createdAt is not nvarchar that why you can't using $iLike

Comment: Why not create two parameters startDt like - 2019-02-27 00:00:00 and endDt 2019-02-27 23:59:59 and use operation Between?

Answer (score 0):

Using function **DateDiff** to get days from between **createdAt** and **dateString**. Need to cast dateString to datetime

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');

var dateString = '01/03/2019';
yourModel.findAll({
    where: sequelize.literal(`DATEDIFF(day,Cast(${dateString} as datetime), createdAt) = 0`)
})
.then(results => {

})
.catch(err => {

});
```